# How to travel to Svalbard?

Tags: planning, norway, islands

I am interested in visiting Svalbard, but I do not know where to start. I know I can maybe book a travel pack or something similar to go there, have some place to sleep and make some tour, but they are normally expensive.

Somebody has been there before and can share his experience? Somebody knows what are the possibilities to go and travel the island?